# Does 14.04 use xorg.conf or ~/.config/monitors.xml?

Tags: xorg

If I have both files `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and `~/.config/monitors.xml`, which one will take precedence??

Comment: Did you figure this out? My monitor settings are currently quite weird now and I can't get it dealt with.